# Iterate through Lists of objects in Firestore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying for days now to iterate through a lists of objects and return a single list of the from it as you'd normally find in realtime database. The following is my database structure:

- cart

  - currentUserID

    - store1Uid

      - autoID

        - productName
        - productCode
        - ...
      - autoID

        - productName
        - productCode
        - ...
    - store2Uid

      - autoID

        - productName
        - productCode
        - ...
      - autoID

        - productName
        - productCode
        - ...

This is my code I'm using to try and return a single list of all the products, regardless of the store it's from:

```
        firebase.firestore()
      .collection('shoppingBags')
      .doc(this.userUid).onSnapshot(shoppingBag => {
        firebase.firestore()
          .collection('shoppingBags')
          .doc(this.userUid).collection(shoppingBag.id).get().then(sBag => {
            sBag.forEach(element => {
              console.log('print results: ', element.data());
            });
          });
      });
```

But it returns null. I've used a similar approach on the realtime database and it worked, is there something I am not doing right as I'm fairly new to firestore?

I've also attached a screenshot below for observance.

[image: database]

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the values of the variables you're using here, and how they match up to actual values in the database, there's not much we can do.  I suggest editing the question to hard code the names of the documents and show a screenshot of actual data so we can see that everything lines up.  It's very likely that you're passing document IDs that don't exist.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson, I've updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: We still can't see that the variables you're using in the query match the data you expect to get from it.

Comment: The only variable I'm using is userUid which I got from firebase.auth().currentUser.uid. You can even substitute userUid for firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.

Comment: I see variables `this.userUid` and `shoppingBag.id`.  Without knowing their values, we have no way of knowing if this query will work the way you expect.

Comment: Could you follow @DougStevenson's instructions and either hardcode the IDs or print their value somewhere. We'd like to discard accessing an unknown document as a possible cause. On another note, could you try to see the retrieved values on `onComplete` and `then`? Also, you are showing us a listing with some kind of structure but it's about `cart`, which is not being accessed on the code that you shared.